# Get one or None from collection

Tags: python, generator

It is quite common to fall into the issue where you have a `N` sized collection but want to work with a singular item (conceptually a `0 or 1` sized collection).

I could write the traditional if:

```
def singular_item(collection):
    if collection:
        return collection[0]
    else:
        return None
```

and simplify to:

```
def singular_item(collection):
    return collection[0] if collection else None
```

But it would not work with iterables, only collections with a defined size. Passing a generator for instance would fail:

```
singular_item((_ for _ in range(10)))
=> TypeError: 'generator' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

So what I normally do is this:

```
def singular_item(collection):
    return next((_ for _ in collection), None) 

singular_item([1]) -> 1
singular_item([1,2,3]) -> 1
singular_item([]) -> None
```

This works well for any collection (or iterable), but it feels somewhat clumsy creating a generator for getting just one item. Also the readability is somewhat killed in it: the two other examples are much more explicit about what the code is trying to do.

So my questions are:

- Is there a better way to do this, maybe by using a builtin function?
- Do you waste resources when creating a generator for getting just one item?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`iter()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#iter) to create an iterable instead:

```
def singular_item(collection):
    return next(iter(collection), None)
```

`iter()` calls `collection.__iter__()` to obtain an iterable object for `next()` to loop over, which could be the `collection` object itself.

Iterators are very efficient otherwise, this approach is just the right way to handle any iterable or sequence.

Answer (score 1):

For the zero or one case, I'd go for (based on the `(conceptually a 0 or 1 sized collection)`):

```
def one(iterable, default=None):
    i = iter(iterable)
    fst = next(i, default)
    try:
        next(i)
        raise ValueError('Must be only 0 or 1 values')
    except StopIteration:
        return fst
```

Comment: Interesting indeed. In this example I dont need to be strict (like a `0 or 1 only`), but this code can help. The only down side is that the iterable gets 1 extra item consumed, but I think there is no practical way to avoid that

Comment: @BrunoPolaco The practical way is don't use this :) (well, you could look ahead and then prepend the items taken back to the start - but that's a bit OTT). This is purely a "I get one value, if I get more - something's wrong" :)